# Syntax highlighting for *.sbt files in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, sbt, sbt-idea

I'm working on a potential module for the Lift Web framework using Scala, SBT 0.12, and IntelliJ IDEA 12.1, and I would like to have syntax highlighting for *.sbt files in IDEA (code awareness would be a bonus).

I have the sbt-idea plugin for sbt which successfully builds my IDEA project. I also have the sbt plugin for IDEA, which allows me to run sbt commands from Run Configurations in IDEA.

When I associate *.sbt files with the Scala file type, IDEA shows all kinds of errors in the sbt script.

Is anyone working on an *.sbt file type for syntax highlighting or code awareness? If so, how do I use it?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably best to suggest this on the [IDEA issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com). I also miss this feature.

Comment: To my knowledge IDEA team is working on full support of sbt build definitions (so you can throw away sbt-idea plugin and work with sbt files in the same way you could work with maven -- no explicit regeneration on change and so on) and promised to roll out this feature soon (original date was late april, but looks like it is detained a little bit). I'm pretty sure highlighting will be the part of that feature, just wait for some (I hope not so long) time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala plugin for IntelliJ IDEA 13 comes with highlighting for .sbt files. See [Built-in SBT Support in IntelliJ IDEA 13](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2013/11/18/built-in-sbt-support-in-intellij-idea-13/):

> Today we are happy to announce that the built-in support for SBT projects is finally here. The newest version of Scala plugin for IntelliJ IDEA 13 (0.23.308) comes with the following list of features:
>
> - Import SBT project
> - Auto-import SBT projects
> - Highlighting for .sbt files

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that .sbt files are really Scala in a way (bar the required blank lines), so associating .sbt files with the Scala editor should not be that far off with regard to syntax highlighting.

Open File -> Settings -> IDE Settings -> File Types. Associate *.sbt with Scala. It's not ideal but a start. At least the editor will look a bit better ;-)

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I tried this and got lots of errors. Do you know of a way to turn these off per file?

Comment: Apologies Jeff, I missed that. Unfortunately I only installed Idea quickly to see if I can help you, but have nuked it since. I use Scala-IDE. However, I did not notice Idea highlighting any errors, but I may have been in dreamland at the time :-p